# How can I use multiple values in SQL variable in PostgresSQL/plpgsql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to declare variable as 
`v_nk varchar;`

then assign the variable 
`v_nk := ''S001234','S23401','S34509','S9900'';`

and use this variable in select query

`select * from mytable where nk in (v_nk);`

I want to use this in one of my program(plpgsql) can you please tell me how I should use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array :

```
v_nk := ARRAY [ 'S001234'::text ,'S23401','S34509','S9900'];
```

OR

```
v_nk := '{S001234,S23401,S34509,S9900}'::text[];
```

and use this variable in select query:

```
select * from mytable where nk = ANY (v_nk);
```

Comment: Hi @RomanTkachuk I tried this it didn't work. I received an error.

Comment: Are you declare v_nk AS text[]?

Comment: Hey @RomanTkachuk ......When I used v_nk : ARRAY ['S001234'::text,'S9900']; I got this error -  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.   Then I used 2nd solution It transforms into run time as      where nk = ANY("{S001234,S23401,S34509,S9900}")     And gives error for "{" bracket

Comment: Can you try: SELECT  ARRAY ['S001234'::text,'S9900'];

Comment: And = ANY('{S001234,S23401,S34509,S9900}'::text[]) - Please use ' NOT "

Comment: I didnt use " it got automatically replaced as I am using this in the script basically in the EXECUTE statement. But I tried again I think this is working but I will test more and will update you. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

you can define array instead of variable like this:

```
DECLARE nk_array    VARCHAR(30)[] = '{'S001234','S23401','S34509','S9900' }';
select * from mytable where nk in nk_array;
```

Comment: Hey @sia  I tried this as well Its giving me error.. Doesn't work

Comment: You messed up the quotes.